# Web application (asp.net MVC) does not show application name in browsing time (after hosting)

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-hosting

When I start my web application I type my pc IP(where application is hosted) and application name as Myip/Myapp its show first page, its ok.
But when I try to go Other page it can't preserve Myip/Myapp portion its only preserve Myip portion. Now i want to fixed "Myip/Myapp" portion of address for every page i want to browse.

First Screen:

[image]

```
After pressing Login where bdms part is missing..
```

[image]

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Please check your File Structure and if you are not able to figure out then i will suggest please use routing it would be a good option.

Comment: When I run from solution it works good but when I host it and want to browsing it misses my application name